# Comments and API v3

Tags: youtube-api

I'm having trouble understanding on what exact course of action should I take in terms of the API v2 to v3 change. We are currently relying on YouTube comments. Information here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/deprecation_faq#parity states that after the April 21 developers will still be able to use v2 API for comment retrieval, while using v2 for everything else.

Our application attempts to capture individual video details (author, length, etc) along with comments. Does that mean that in order to have this functionality after the April 21 cutoff for v2, we will need to be using both v2 for video details and v3 for video comments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

More detail in here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5046

v3 of the comments feature is about to launch. v2 version of comments feeds won't be turned down in April 21st and will be open for a grace period.

We suggest you to migrate all features to v3 (including comments when it's launched) asap.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you know the exact date when v3 comments will launch? Main issue is that April 21st is fast approaching and we might not have enough time to implement the new API in our application. (we are trying to minimise the time when users are not able to get comments)

Comment: Can you update us on the length of the grace period?