# What happens to the api calls that v2 comments require during the grace period?

Tags: youtube-api

Another SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335549/comments-and-api-v3) mentions that the YouTube api v2 will be turned off April 21st and the comments functionality will be left on for a grace period.

Some of the client libraries require parts of the v2 api that will be turned off to get comments.  For example in the .net library you need to pass a v2 video object to get video comments.   To get that v2 video object there is a separate get video api call.  What will happen to these required api calls during the grace period?

```
var v2Video = _request.Retrieve<Video>(uri) 

_request.GetComments(v2Video)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should migrate all other requests to v3. You can use the videos.list call for that, then use v2 to request comments.

In general all you need is a video id for that getcomment method. So you can easily recreate a resource with only knowing the id.