# When will the YouTube v2 (comments) deprecation grace period end?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We're working on migrating from the YouTube v2 comments to YouTube v3 within our our application.

We are aware of the fact that YouTube API v2 is deprecated, is there an estimated date as to when the v2 api grace period will end?  It would be very helpful for us to know so we can make sure the v3 is in place before the end of the grace period.

**UPDATE**

Check this SO question for details about the grace period. 
[Comments and API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335549/comments-and-api-v3/29353151#29353151)

Answer (score 1):

The only information I can find is:

> **Note**: The YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of
>   March 4, 2014. Please refer to our [deprecation policy](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms#deprecation) for more
>   information. Please use the YouTube Data API (v3) for new integrations
>   and migrate applications still using the v2 API to the v3 API as well.

Which lead to [April 20, 2015](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms#deprecation) which is around the same date that the Oauth deprecations where supposed to also stop working.   I heard from a Googler that everything wasn't going to be shut off at once, its kind of like a rolling shut down.   If its still working I think you should try and make your changes ASAP it sounds like it could stop working at anytime.

Not a 100% answer but it was to long for a comment.

Comment: Thanks.  If you can find out any more I'd really appreciate it.  The YouTube v3 comments were released less than a month ago so we're trying to get it updated quickly.  A more concrete date would really help us.